# Python--When is timedelta object processed?

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have the following Django model:

```
   created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I now need a model object method which shows the # of hours since creation.  I tried the following:

```
  def hours_live(self):
    diff=((datetime.datetime.now - self.created).seconds)/3600
    return diff
```

but it threw a TypeError

```
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

I then went with

```
 def hours_live(self):
    diff=((datetime.datetime.now() - self.created).seconds)/3600
    return diff
```

My question is whether the datetime.datetime.now() expression is executed only one time here or whether it executes each time hours_live is called.

Will this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example, it will be executed every time the function is called. The gotcha is when datetime.datetime.now() is used as a default value for a parameter in a function definition. In that case, it is executed just once when the module is loaded.

For example: (this is dangerous because *since* is calculated only once when the module is loaded):

```
def hours_live(since=datetime.datetime.now()):
    return since - self.created
```

You should rather do:

```
def hours_live(since=None):
    if not since:
        since = datetime.datetime.now()
    return since - self.created
```

Answer (score 6):

`datetime.datetime.now` is a method. When you call it without parentheses, you are referring to the method itself, and you can't subtract a time from a method. When you call it *with* parentheses, you are calling the method, getting the return value, and then using that for subtraction.

Answer (score 3):

Of course it's executed every time `hours_live` is called, it's a normal function call.